# TypeError: this.state.user.map is not a function in react

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value from `days_free` from an array within an object returned from a rest api. However, I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: this.state.user.map is not a function`

The data is structured like so:

```
{
  "available": true,
  "offers": [
    {
      "days_free": 30,
      "description": "Woo!"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to map the array within the object and get the value with

```
const daysFree = this.state.user.map((daysFree, i) => {
  return (
    <span>{daysFree.days_free}</span>
  )
})
```

From my component:

```
class CancelOffer extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      user: []
    }
    this.processData = this.processData.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchContent(this.processData)
  }

  fetchContent (cb) {
    superagent
      .get('/api/data')
      .then(cb)
  }

  processData (data) {
    this.setState({
      user: data.body
    })
  }
  render () {
  const content = this.props.config.contentStrings
  const daysFree = this.state.user.map((daysFree, i) => {
    return (
      <span>{daysFree.days_free}</span>
    )
  })

    return (
      <div className='offer'>
        <h2 className='offer-heading md'>Heading</h2>
        <p className='offer-subpara'>text {daysFree} </p>
        <div className='footer-links'>
          <a href='/member' className='btn btn--primary btn--lg'>accept</a>
          <a href='/' className='cancel-link'>cancel</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default CancelOffer
```

Comment: To seems to imply that `data.body` is likely not an array. Find out what it is and perform the necessary action to convert the value to an array.

Comment: probably just need to do `user: data.body.offers`

Comment: As @dave said; if you're trying to map over the Object you outlined in your post, it won't work. You need to map over the array _within_ the Object. Which, as he said, is `data.body.offers` (probably).

Comment: @dave - That works. If you can post that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.body` is an object, if you want to loop over the offers, you need to do

```
processData (data) {
    this.setState({
        user: data.body.offers
    })
}
```